# Clear pyglet resource cache

Tags: python, resources, pyglet

Is there a way to clear the resources cache in pyglet? The source image for a resource changes on disk and I need to reload it, but pyglet uses the cached resource instead.
This is what I do:

```
pyglet.resource.path = [self.path]
pyglet.resource.reindex()
self.img = pyglet.resource.image(self.filename)
```

Then the image file changes on the disk and I want to reload it and I do the above again, but pyglet seems to use the cached image instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem when using pyglet. This is the solution that I came up with:

```
def clear_cache(filename):
        if filename in pyglet.resource._default_loader._cached_images:
            del pyglet.resource._default_loader._cached_images[filename]
```

It works for me!

Explanation:

After poking around in the `pyglet` source, it seems that the `resource` module records the image names in a dictionary called `_cached_images`.

It also seems that when you use the resource module like you are doing in your example, an object called `_default_loader` is created in the resource module. Therefore, the cache is found in `_default_loader._cached_images`.

I'm sure there's a better way to accomplish what I did, such as sub-classing resource and adding my own `clear_cache` method there. But I'm new to programming, and I didn't quite understand everything in the `resource` module, so this was the best that I came up with.